# R: How to get a value in data frame column depending on sequence and values in other columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame, df. The data frame i ordered by v1 and v2.
For each group of unique value in v1 (values 1, 2 and 3 in sample data) I want to compute a new variable, v5.

The value of v5 depends on values of v3 and v4:
If v3 == "New" then v5 == v4.
If v3 == "Old" then v5 gets the value of v4 in the row where the first preceding value in v3 equals "New". All within same "group" of v1.

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(v1=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), 
             v2=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4),
             v3=c("New", "Old", "Old","New", "Old", "New","New", "New", "Old","Old"),
             v4=c("A","B","C","X","Y","Z","A","B","C","D")) 


v1 v2  v3 v4
1  1 New  A  
1  2 Old  B
1  3 Old  C
2  1 New  X
2  2 Old  Y
2  3 New  Z
3  1 New  A
3  2 New  B
3  3 Old  C
3  4 Old  D
```

Desired output:

```
   v1 v2  v3 v4 v5
    1  1 New  A  A
    1  2 Old  B  A
    1  3 Old  C  A
    2  1 New  X  X
    2  2 Old  Y  X
    2  3 New  Z  Z
    3  1 New  A  A
    3  2 New  B  B
    3  3 Old  C  B
    3  4 Old  D  B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can also use the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df <- data.frame(v1=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), 
                 v2=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4),
                 v3=c("New", "Old", "Old","New", "Old", "New","New", "New", "Old","Old"),
                 v4=c("A","B","C","X","Y","Z","A","B","C","D"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
df %>% 
  group_by(v1) %>%
  mutate(v5=ifelse(v3=="New", v4, NA),
         v5=na.locf(v5))
# Source: local data frame [10 x 5]
# Groups: v1 [3]
# 
#       v1    v2    v3    v4    v5
#    (dbl) (dbl) (chr) (chr) (chr)
# 1      1     1   New     A     A
# 2      1     2   Old     B     A
# 3      1     3   Old     C     A
# 4      2     1   New     X     X
# 5      2     2   Old     Y     X
# 6      2     3   New     Z     Z
# 7      3     1   New     A     A
# 8      3     2   New     B     B
# 9      3     3   Old     C     B
# 10     3     4   Old     D     B
```

Comment: Great. Thx @ docendo discimus

Answer (score 1):

We can try with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'v1', we `replace` the 'v4' elements that corresponds to 'Old' values in 'v3' with NA and then use `na.locf` (from `library(zoo)`) to replace the `NA` values by the preceding non-NA values, assign (`:=`) the output to create the new column 'v5'.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
setDT(df)[, v5:= na.locf(replace(v4, v3=='Old', NA)) , by = v1]
df
#    v1 v2  v3 v4 v5
# 1:  1  1 New  A  A
# 2:  1  2 Old  B  A
# 3:  1  3 Old  C  A
# 4:  2  1 New  X  X
# 5:  2  2 Old  Y  X
# 6:  2  3 New  Z  Z
# 7:  3  1 New  A  A
# 8:  3  2 New  B  B
# 9:  3  3 Old  C  B
#10:  3  4 Old  D  B
```

---

Or we can use `ave` from `base R`

```
df$v5 <- with(df, ave(replace(v4, v3=='Old', NA),v1, FUN= na.locf))
```